# How do I include a Chrome Javascript API in the background.js in a Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've just recently began working on my own packaged app for Google Chrome. Since it's mostly just standard HTML, CSS, and Javascript, I have found it fairly easy to put together. However, I've been having difficulty using the API features added by Google and can find very little information on it.

I've tried to add in the API to the *background.js* 's code in several different places, but each time, the app fails to launch (nothing happens when I open it).

Here's what I found on developer.chrome.com that I've been using as a reference:

```
chrome.app.window.create(string url, object options, function callback)
```

And here's the background.js page that I'm using with *frame('none'),* added in:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
 chrome.app.window.create('window.html', frame('none'), {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 700,
      'height': 600,
      }
 });
});
```

I know this is probably a stupid question with an obvious answer, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you gotten any of the Chrome app samples working? Start with them, and then modify them to suit your needs. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As kzahel mentions the syntax for frame is wrong. It also should be merged into the next argument you've provided for bounds, which is also part of the options.

What you want is something more like:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    frame: 'none',
    bounds: {
      'width': 700,
      'height': 600
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you both! I realize how stupid that was now. I've never had to call a function before at the time of the question and had no clue what I was doing. 

Thank you again! Hopefully I'll have all of the basics down soon and not have to ask any more obvious questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. instead of "frame('none')", it should read {frame:'none'}.
It's not launching because you're trying to call frame as a function. chrome.app.window.create wants an object as the second argument.